# Elasticsearch slowed down suddenly

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch for my website. Everything was normal, I received response within max 60ms but it suddenly slowed down. Now I'm getting response in min 200ms.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your web server is causing this rather than the Elasticsearch service itself. If you can, check the connection logs on your server to see if it is receiving a lot of requests. If you are hosting your Elasticsearch instance on a public-facing website, it's very possible that someone, or multiple people are sending a lot of requests or queries to it which could be causing it to slow down.

It may be a good idea to set up your Elasticsearch behind Apache2 or something similar to protect against this. That way, you can limit the requests to specific IPs and restrict the HTTP methods called against the Elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: Nobody else uses Elasticsearch right now. It's development stage.

Comment: What are the specifications of the machine running Elasticsearch? I would've commented this before, but I can't leave comments yet because my rep is too low.

Comment: 32GB RAM, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v2 @ 3.70GHz 8 Cores, 2x 4TB HDD (not SDD), Centos 6, nginx

Comment: Have you limited your JVM memory allocation at all? According to this article, having 32GB can cause it to run slowly. [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html)